# ReactNative: uniform parameter usage in components possible?

Tags: react-native

If I have a ReactNative Component with arguments then I use it in that way.

**Use it in the parent**

```
<MyComp param1="foobar"/>
```

**Access the parameter inside of the compoent**

```
<Text>Parameter is {this.props.param1}</Text>
```

If I use the component in navigation it is completely different.

**Use it**

```
<Button title={"goto"} onPress={() => 
    this.props.navigation.navigate("MyComp", {param1: "foobar"})}/>
```

**Access parameter**

```
<Text>Parameter is {this.props.navigation.getParam ("param1", "??")}</Text>
```

Is there a way to make that uniform? It would be nice if the component would be independent of its origin. These are my first steps with React and React Native. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: maybe you can use `this.props.navigation.getParam ("param1", this.props.param1)`, second parameter is the fallback. Or in your component build a logic in the constructor to check which value is sent.

Comment: Does not work because _this.props.navigation_ is undefined if the component is called without navigation and therefore the default-handling of getParam is not possible.

Comment: that's true, so you have to implement the logic in the constructor of your component